# Importing ImageQT in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to run a script for image analysis and get an error while importing ImageQT.

The Code:

```py
import random 
import sys, os 
import openslide 
import numpy as np 
import imreg_dft as ird 
import scipy as sp 
from scipy import ndimage 
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv 
from PIL import Image 
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap, QCursor, QPen
```

The Error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) Cell 
In[1], line 10
       8 from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
       9 from PIL import Image
 ---> 10 from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
      11 from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
      12 from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap, QCursor, QPen 
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageQt' from 'PIL.ImageQt' (/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageQt.py)
```

I have searched for this problem and the only thing I found was reinstalling PIL. Sadly this did not solve the Problem.

When I remove the line the rest of the imports run without problem.

Does anybody have an idea what I could try?

Also I am new at this field, please let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: Use `from PIL import ImageQt` and reference the class as `ImageQt.ImageQt`.  `ImageQt` is evidently not a separately-importable module